Display "Free Shipping" for WooCommerce Cart Products with Zero Shipping Cost
I'm trying to display "Free Shipping" for products in the WooCommerce cart that have a shipping cost of 0. I am using Webiwork Shipping Per Product WooCommerce plugin to add per-product shipping, and I want to show this message only for those products, while leaving products with non-zero shipping charges unchanged, like this screenshot:

I attempted to use the following code:
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'display_free_shipping_for_cart_items', 20, 2);
function display_free_shipping_for_cart_items($cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
    $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();

    foreach ($packages as $package) {
        if (isset($package['contents'][$cart_item_key])) {
            $product = $package['contents'][$cart_item_key];

            if (!empty($package['rates'])) {
                $shipping_rate = reset($package['rates']);
                $shipping_cost = $shipping_rate->cost;

                if ($shipping_cost == 0) {
                    echo '<p class="product-shipping-cost">Free Shipping</p>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

But it seems to either show nothing or doesn’t work as expected.

I think that your theme is customizing the template cart/cart.php located in a "woocommerce" subfolder inside the main theme… So you should use a child theme to override that template by copying it to your child theme inside a "woocommerce' subfolder > "cart" sub-subfolder… Then you can open edit it and add in the desired location, simply: if ( $_product->is_virtual() ) { echo '<p class="product-shipping-cost">Free Shipping</p>'; }.

Few steps here to make it happen safely.

define free shipping class, with known slug:
setting shipping class

set the shipping class on your product:
setting shipping class to product


add this code, that adds the title after the price on cart page, but you can adjust the hook to the wanted location:
<?php 

// Add 'Free Shipping' text after price if the product has a specific shipping class
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'add_free_shipping_text_to_cart_item', 10, 3);

function add_free_shipping_text_to_cart_item($price_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{
    // Define the shipping class slug for free shipping
    $free_shipping_class_slug = 'free-shipping';
    // Get the product object
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $is_free_shipping = $product->get_shipping_class() == $free_shipping_class_slug;
    // Check if the product has the specified shipping class
    if ($is_free_shipping) {
        // Append "Free Shipping" text after the price
        $price_html .= '<span class="free-shipping-text">Free Shipping</span>';
    }

    return $price_html;
}


Thank you so much for taking the time to provide the solution! I really appreciate it. I will definitely check out your suggestion. However, I had already looked into the plugin files and managed to extend its functionality by adding custom code to display the shipping cost under the product title on the cart page. The code is working as expected now, but I’ll keep your approach in mind. Thanks again for your help!
